# Pandas grouping values and getting most recent date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large csv file that I read into Pandas that gets me a DataFrame for "Community_Name" and "Date"  its about 186k lines with about 120 unique "Community_Names" and a range of Dates.  I would like to Group the data by Community and find the most recent Date for each in the file.  I will use this later on to pull data from each community up to that most recent date later on.

I am struggling with getting the most recent date value for each community.  I thought the .max() would work, but it returns the greatest value overall rather than for each community...

```
with open('communitydates.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        date = line['Date'] + " " + line['Year']
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d %Y').strftime('%Y %d %m')
        community_name = line['Community']
        entry = community_name, date
        dates_list.append(entry)df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)

df.columns = ["Community", "Date"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y %d %m').max()
grouped_by_community = df.groupby("Community")
recent_date_by_community = grouped_by_community.first()
```

Ideally I want to convert the DataFrame into a Dictionary or List to do the check later on.

```
max_dates = recent_date_by_community.to_dict('index')


for k in max_dates:
    print(k, max_dates[k]['Date'])
```

Which currently gives me this...but...the date is the same for all 102 communities vs the actual date in the file.

```
Addison 2019-10-09 00:00:00
```

I assuming I am using the .max() statement incorrectly, but have not been able to figure out how change it.

Comment: `df.groupby('Community').Date.max()` or `df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('Community', keep='last')`.

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang, the .Date.max() worked correctly for me!